# Dual display doesnt turn on after I try to unlock

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have done a dual boot on my laptop with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.Since the day I started using Ubuntu, everything has worked just fine except the fact that whenever I lock my PC and then try to log back in, the screen just doesn't show up. I have my monitor connected to my laptop on the HDMI-1 port (making that display the primary one).
I then have to disconnect the HDMI cable of my monitor and reconnect, and then the login screen pops up, thereby making it difficult to always connect and reconnect.
I assume it to be any sort of glitch or error in the configuration. I had also checked through the display settings, and everything there seems fine.
Please suggest a remedy for it, as it irritates me a lot.
Note: I have also updated my drivers (the default one and the NVidea driver).